# using fork in an if-statement/ managing processes

Tags: c, fork

I have this bit of code:

```
   printf("L1 ");

   if(fork() != 0) {
      printf("L2 ");

      if(fork() != 0) {

         printf("L3 ");
         fork();
      }
   }
printf("End \n");
```

As an exercise I am trying to figure out some examples of valid/ invalid output that would result from running this code (without actually running it).

I am still a bit confused with how the fork() method works exactly within an if-statement. I know that once it is called it returns twice, indicating that it has created two processes.So that if I did something like,

```
printf("L1 ");
fork();
printf("L2 ");
```

I would get `L1 L2 L2`

But I am still shaky on how it works in in statements like in the first bit of code.

Here is what I think are a few valid/ invalid outputs:

```
Valid: L1 L1 L2
       L1 L2 L3
       L1 L2 L1

Invalid: (Anything hat doesn't start with L1)
      L1 L2 L2
      L1 L3 L2
```

Doe these make sense? Is there an simple way to explain sort of what is going on in the if-statements so that I can get a general idea as to how the fork() works in them? And are these output values correct/ incorrect?

Comment: The tag info right here on SO has a pretty simple explaination: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fork/info

Comment: yes thank you. I have that concept down. What I was looking for was more of an explanation as to how it works within the if-statement and if my output made logical sense with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `fork()` calls all fail, there'll only be one process, so it will print:

```
L1 L2 L3 End
```

If every `fork()` call succeeds, then:

1. Assuming line buffered or fully buffered output,
2. There will be 4 lots of print out, but their sequence is indeterminate, and could be (but probably won't be) interleaved on the output.
3. Each output will start with `L1` and end with `End`.
4. When `fork()` returns a non-zero value, it is the parent process.
5. The first `if` fails in the first child, so it prints `L1 End`.
6. The first `if` passes in the parent, and the subsequent outputs will then include `L2`.
7. The second `if` fails in the second child, so it prints `L1 L2 End`.
8. The second `if` passes in the parent, and the subsequent outputs will then include `L3`.
9. The third `fork()` creates two processes (or creates one and continues in the parent), both of which print `L1 L2 L3 End`.

So, the output will consist of:

```
L1 End
L1 L2 End
L1 L2 L3 End
L1 L2 L3 End
```

but the sequence is not guaranteed.

---

After posting the analysis above, I checked it by running it, and the first sample run produced:

```
L1 End 
L1 L2 L3 End 
L1 L2 End 
L1 L2 L3 End
```

---

Note that if the output is non-buffered, then the output is different.  `L1` will appear once; `L2` will appear once; `L3` will appear once; and `End` will appear four times.

One possible sequence is:

```
L1 L2 End 
L3 End 
End 
End
```

Another observed sequence (second of two runs) was:

```
L1 L2 L3 End 
End End 

End
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the child of each fork proceeds directly to the `printf("End")`. Only the parent will print `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, so they'll only be printed once each, in that order. Mixed in with that output would be the `End`s of the children (and the final end of the parent).

Comment: Ah so you're saying that a valid output would be (l1,l2,l3, end) or (l1,end,l2,end, l3, end)? Why does the child proceed directly to the end statement?

Comment: In the child, `fork()` returns zero, while the parent get's the child's process ID.

Comment: The third fork creates two processes, both of which print `L1 L2 L3 End`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, But all that's left after the third fork is `printf("End\n")`! And I wouldn't say `fork` creates two processes; it creates one new process and the old one just continues on its way along with the new one.

Comment: @ooga: OK; I was sloppy in my phraseology.  After the third fork, there are two processes, the parent and the child, both of which proceed on to add the `End`.  And both of which have `L1 L2 L3` already in the print buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Ohhh, I didn't even think about the print buffer! I see what you mean. It's worse than I thought.