# fork function process graph, valid and invalid outputs

Tags: c, process, fork

```
printf("L1 \n");
  if (fork() != 0) {
    printf("L2 \n");
    if (fork() != 0) {
      printf("L3 \n");
      fork();
    }
  }
printf("End \n");
```

I am having a hard time understanding this code. Could someone explain/ display what the process graph would look like? Also, a valid and invalid sequence.

My thought of the process graph was something like this:

L1 will hold two L2 processes then each L2 processes will hold 2 L3 processes and each L3 processes will hold an end processes. Is this correct?

A valid sequence for me was L1, L2, L3, End

An invalid one would be L2, L1, End this is because L1 must come before L2, L2 is dependent on L1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using fork in an if-statement/ managing processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800437/using-fork-in-an-if-statement-managing-processes). There's one difference; these `printf()` formats end with `\n`.  The answer still depends on the buffering mode.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the code properly indented and with numbered lines.

```
1.  printf("L1 \n");
2.  if(fork() != 0) {
3.    printf("L2 \n");
4.    if(fork() != 0) {
5.      printf("L3 \n");
6.      fork();
7.    }
8.  }
9.  printf("End \n");
```

Let's assume that when you run it for the first time the father's PID is 1000 (it doesn't matter what number is it, anyway it depends on OS, but we're making this assumption to make it clear on the process tree).

### Line1:

Process `PID==1000` prints `L1`. So far we have:

**Process Tree:**

```
           1000
```

**Output:**

```
L1
```

---

### Line2:

Process `PID==1000` forks, creating a child process (assume it's `PID==1001`). According to `man 2 fork` only process `PID==1000` is entering the if block, since `fork()` will return `0` for the child process.

Process `PID==1000` continues at Line 3 where it will print `L2` and then continue to Line 5, whereas process `PID==1001` jumps to Line 9, after the `if` block, so it will print `End`. So far, we have:

**Process Tree:**

```
  -------------- 1000
  |
  |
 1001
```

**Output:**

```
L1
L2
End
```

---

### Line 4:

Process `PID==1000` forks again, creating child process `PID==1002`.

Again, process `PID==1002` jumps to Line 9, printing `End` because `fork()` returns `0` for it, whereas father process `PID==1000` continues at Line 5, printing `L3`, and after that it's going to Line 6. So far we have:

**Process Tree:**

```
   ------------ 1000
   |              |
   |              |
  1001          1002
```

**Output:**

```
L1
L2
End
L3
End
```

---

### Line 6:

Father process `PID==1000` forks again. creating child process `PID==1003`. After that, both father and child processes go to Line 9, so they both print `End`. So finally, we have:

**Process Tree:**

```
   ------------- 1000 --------------
   |               |               |
   |               |               |
  1001           1002            1003
```

**Output:**

```
L1
L2
End
L3
End
End
End
```

---

To see that by yourself, you could change `printf()` in your current code using `getpid(2)` to see exactly what will be printed by each process. Code will be like this:

```
1.  printf("(pid %d)\tL1\n", (int) getpid());
2.  if (fork() != 0) {
3.      printf("(pid %d)\tL2\n", (int) getpid());
4.      if (fork() != 0) {
5.          printf("(pid %d)\tL3\n", (int) getpid());
6.          fork();
7.      }
8.  }
9.  printf("(pid %d)\tEnd\n", (int) getpid());
```

Comment: Would you care to pontificate on the difference in output between `./test-program` and `./test-program | cat`. It adds to the fun.  See also the duplicate question (where the `printf()` formats did not include a newline, so using unbuffered output got output similar to what you get normally here).