# Forking WITHOUT waiting

Tags: c, switch-statement, fork, wait

I am unsure if I am correctly going about this, I am trying to create 7 processes total via...

```
void err_sys(const char* x)
{
   perror(x);
   exit(1);
}


for(i = 1; i < 7; i++){
  switch(parent = fork()){
      case -1:
         err_sys("fork error");
      case 0:       //child
         printf("I'm the child, number %d(%d)\n", i, getpid());
         break;
      default:      //parent
         printf("I'm the parent(%d)\n", getpid());
         break;
  }
    if(parent)
       break;        //loop break
}
```

When I run it with prog | cat > file I get 6 outputs of "I am the parent", followed with various amounts of children each. However, there are 6 children made with unique pids. The other parent pids, other than the first match a child pid. Is this just some problem that comes with output due to forking?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not incorrect *a priori*; it does what it does.  The issue is 'does it do what you want it to do', and that is not clear because you've not clearly stated what you are trying to do.

One reason you get 6 processes is that you have a loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
```

This counts 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and stops.  You need to use one of two idioms:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)      // Idiomatic C
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)     // Less idiomatic C
```

Assuming that `err_sys()` does not return when called (if it did, you'd need a `break;` after it), then:

1. The process forks.  If the fork fails, the process exits via `err_sys()`.
2. If the process is the child (so the misnamed variable `parent` is set to 0), then the code prints "I'm the child" and then leaves the switch, and iterates around the loop again.
3. If the process is the parent (so the misnamed variable `parent` is set to a non-zero value), it prints "I'm the parent" and then leaves both the switch and the loop.

Only the child from the first fork gets to re-execute the loop.  However, each child except the last gets to identify itself as the parent on the next iteration of the loop.

#### Buffered I/O

Note that buffered I/O complicates things.  If the output of the program is written to the terminal, you will get line buffered output by default.  Each newline causes the data to be written to the terminal.  However, when the output goes to a pipe, it is fully buffered; the data only gets written to the terminal when the buffer is full, or the process is exiting (or closes standard output for some other reason).  Thus, when the output goes to a pipe, the first child has the output from just its operations, but the second child has the data printed, but not flushed, by the first child in its buffer as well as what it wrote.  The third child has 3 process's worth of output, and so on.

You could add `fflush(0)` or `fflush(stdout)` after the print statements (or just after the end of the `switch`, before the `if`) and see what a difference it makes.  You can also run the code without redirecting to a pipe and see what a difference that makes.

Comment: How come you don't upvote questions like this?  It looks clear and complete enough.

Comment: @wallyk: Usually, I don't up-vote a question because I've answered sufficiently similar questions sufficiently often (and sufficiently recently) that it doesn't meet my 'novelty' criterion, even though I can't necessarily be bothered to chase down the duplicate(s).  For example, [Using `fork()` in an `if` statement — managing processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800437/) is fundamentally about the same issues. True, this uses a `switch` instead of an `if`, but that is incidental.  Then there was [`fork()` function process graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853148/), and …

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the uniqueness or novelty of a question was part of the criteria.  The upvote hover text is *This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)*.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: with an iteration of getting 6 children, doesn't my parent process count as number 7, process wise? err_sys has also been added to show the functionality.

Comment: @wallyk: I'm not sure whether it is officially part of the criteria;  I use it because there are a lot of answered questions on SO that are very close to what is being asked now, but finding the duplicate (or sufficiently close to duplicate) is hard.  Whether that's the official stance is a separate discussion. If you look at my voting record, you'll see it is heavily skewed towards up-voting answers (over up-voting questions, and even more so compared with down-voting either questions or answers). That's me; I'm only one; there are many on SO to compensate for any deficiencies in what I do.

Comment: @DanielAnthony: it depends on how you want to count.  There are 6 child processes; there are 6 parent processes; there are 7 separate process IDs used.  (There's one parent process that never considers itself a child; there's one child process that never considers itself a parent; the other 5 count themselves as both child and then parent.)  Your code creates 6 processes; the seventh is created a priori by the shell.  I don't think it is worth making a big fuss over; 5, 6, 7, 8 are all much the same — truly, the interesting numbers are zero, one, many.